# filter on multiple selected columns and one condition

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Working with a larga dataset I am using `dplyr` and the `tidyverse`. Regarding subsetting based on conditions the following problem came up. Working conditions are:

```
filter_if(is.numeric, all_vars(. > 0 & .< 1)
```

or

```
mutate_at(vars(starts_with("x")), ~na_if(., 0))
```

but what to do, if I want to combine the two "types":

```
filter_at(vars(starts_with("x")), any_vars(. < 10))
```

or

```
filter_at(vars(starts_with("x")), all_vars(. < 10))
```

does not work. How to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Try `filter(across(starts_with("x"), any(. < 10)))` - `across` has superseded all of the `_if`, `_at`, etc verbs

Comment: Both your `filter_at`are correct and will work as intended.

Comment: @MarBlo it is weard, seems to have problems with overlapping functions/packages. After a restart everything works well. Thanks!